# Does the garbage collector preserve an array that is referenced only by raw pointers?

Tags: arrays, garbage-collection, heap-memory, d

I'd like to allocate an array of elements from the garbage collected heap, and access those elements only through raw pointers. Is the garbage collector capable of reclaiming that block of memory after (and not before) all the pointers that used to point to it have gone out of scope?

I was thinking of doing it like this:

```
{
    int* ptrToArray1 = (new int[](100)).ptr;
    int* ptrToArray2 = ptrToArray1;
    int* ptrToArray3 = ptrToArray1 + 10;

    ptrToArray1 += 50;
    ptrToArray2 += 99;

    *ptrToArray1 = 123;
    *ptrToArray2 = 456;
    *ptrToArray3 = 789;

    ptrToArray1 -= 42;
    ptrToArray2 -= 24;

    //... and so on ... Is the array data guaranteed to be there?
}
// Now that all the pointers are out of scope, can the
// garbage collector reclaim the memory block of that array?
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your scenario will work.

Two things:

1. The garbage collector is conservative. That means it scans the raw words of the stack, registers, and the GC heap. Anything that looks like a pointer to GC-allocated memory will be considered to be such, and therefore keep that piece of memory live.
2. The garbage collector allows interior pointers. The reason for this is two-fold. First, it's fairly common (in a systems language) to iterate through raw memory using just pointer arithmetic, so the GC has to handle a situation like that, where only an offset pointer points to the GC memory. Second, interfaces in D are really just offsets from the base object, so these need to keep the original object live.

It's worth noting that interior pointers significantly slow down the marking phase of the garbage collector, but in a systems language like D, not supporting interior pointers would be unreasonable.

Finally, note that if you store a pointer to GC-allocated memory outside the GC heap and the stack/registers, *it will not be picked up by the GC*. That is, if you store some array's `.ptr` in some `malloc`'d memory, and then throw away all references to it, it won't be considered live, for example.

Comment: Thanks, that answer made the whole thing considerably clearer to me.

Comment: Apart from GC heap and stack/registers, TLS memory and IIRC the data segment (static variables) are scanned as well.

Comment: @jpf Yes, I forgot to mention those (though they are generalized as GC root ranges in druntime).